# How start celery worker in Django project

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, celery

I have a `Django` project with the directory structure mentioned below. I am trying to use `Celery` for running tasks in the background. I have facing some trouble while running the `worker`. Whenever I issue the following command, I get an error.

**Command**

```
$ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

From the `project`directory where `manage.py` resides

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'

From the `project`directory where `celery.py` resides

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'

From the `app`directory where `tasks.py` resides

> AttributeError: module 'tasks' has no attribute 'celery'

**Project Structure**

```
project
    |-- app
         |-- admin.py
         |-- apps.py
         |-- __init__.py
         |-- models.py
         |-- tasks.py
         |-- tests.py
         |-- urls.py
         |-- views.py
    |-- project
            |-- celery.py
            |-- settings.py
            |-- __init__.py
            |-- urls.py
            |-- wsgi.py
    |-- manage.py
```

Comment: `celery -A project worker --loglevel=info ` from top level

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use project name to start celery. Since your `celery.py` located inside `project` directory you need to run from the project's root directory following:

```
celery -A project worker --loglevel=info
```

Instead of

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

Check example [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker).