# Connection Django + Celery + RabbitMQ with Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, celery

Im having some issues to run celery tasks in my django project, I am currently using rabbitmq as the broker. When I run the "docker compose up" and everything is on, if I run "celery status" inside the django container it fails with "kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused", but if I run it on my machine it works giving me the worker, how can I fix this?

Here is my docker compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - django
    volumes:
      - postgres_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    networks:
      - django
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - rabbitmq_log:/var/log/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672

  celery_worker:
    build: .
    command: celery -A loan_manager worker --loglevel=info
    networks:
      - django
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672//
      - DATABASE_NAME=postgres
      - DATABASE_USER=postgres
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

  django_app:
    build: .
    command: > 
      sh -c "python3 manage.py makemigrations --noinput && 
      python3 manage.py migrate --noinput && 
      python3 manage.py shell < ./utils/create_superuser.py && 
      python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    networks:
      - django
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672//
      - DATABASE_NAME=postgres
      - DATABASE_USER=postgres
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq

volumes:
  postgres_db:
  rabbitmq_data:
  rabbitmq_log:

networks:
  django:
```

And here is the celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "loan_manager.settings")
app = Celery(
    "loan_manager",
    broker=os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_URL"),
    backend="rpc://",
    broker_connection_retry_on_startup=True,
)
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=["application/json"],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER="json",
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER="json",
)
app.autodiscover_tasks(["apps"])
```

This are the logs inside my celery worker:

```
2023-06-16 16:09:25 [2023-06-16 19:09:25,296: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@rabbitmq:5672//
2023-06-16 16:09:25 [2023-06-16 19:09:25,303: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
2023-06-16 16:09:26 [2023-06-16 19:09:26,318: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
2023-06-16 16:09:26 [2023-06-16 19:09:26,334: INFO/MainProcess] celery@c9c1728a9b1b ready.
2023-06-16 16:09:18  
2023-06-16 16:09:18  -------------- celery@c9c1728a9b1b v5.3.0 (emerald-rush)
2023-06-16 16:09:18 --- ***** ----- 
2023-06-16 16:09:18 -- ******* ---- Linux-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.28 2023-06-16 19:09:18
2023-06-16 16:09:18 - *** --- * --- 
2023-06-16 16:09:18 - ** ---------- [config]
2023-06-16 16:09:18 - ** ---------- .> app:         loan_manager:0x7ff2da1b5d10
2023-06-16 16:09:18 - ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@rabbitmq:5672//
2023-06-16 16:09:18 - ** ---------- .> results:     rpc://
2023-06-16 16:09:18 - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
2023-06-16 16:09:18 -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
2023-06-16 16:09:18 --- ***** ----- 
2023-06-16 16:09:18  -------------- [queues]
2023-06-16 16:09:18                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
2023-06-16 16:09:18                 
2023-06-16 16:09:18 
2023-06-16 16:09:18 [tasks]
2023-06-16 16:09:18   . apps.loan_proposal.tasks.process_loan_proposals
```

This is my docker ps:
[image]

Comment: maybe it will not fix, but you rabbimq service depends_on rabbitmq. Also, post you `docker-compose ps` to check if everything is up and running. You have defined the network twice on rabbitmq

Comment: @pleasedontbelong Added more info, still having issues.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your django project structure is similar to what [celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django) suggest, you have to specify the name of the folder where the `celery.py` resides while runnig `celery status`.

For below project structure:

```
- proj/
  - manage.py
  - proj/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
```

you'd have to run `celery -A loan_manager status`

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480639/how-start-celery-worker-in-django-project) answer.